# Recode variable depending on frequencies

Tags: r, recode

I have a variable 'Specialisme' which include different specialisms, which prevent in different frequencies (see the picture below). This is for a specific year, but in another year, the sequence of the specialismes can differ.

[image]

What I want: I would like to generate a code, that put the specialisms together which prevent less than 20 times in that year. This year, it will be number 1 till 15 (CAR till REV) but another year it can be the first 12 specialisms, of 20 specialisms. And this year, GYF can be included, but next year maybe not.

How can I 'write' that in a code?
DPLYR and mutate? Something else?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible data example instead of a picture.

Answer (score 1):

The 'forcats' package provides a family of `fct_lump_*` functions for this purpose, which you can use if you convert `Specialisme` into a factor. The function needed for this case is `fct_lump_min`.

```r
require(dplyr)
require(forcats)

my_df <- mutate(
                my_df,
                Specialisme = fct_lump_min(Specialisme, min = 15, w = Frequentie)
                )
```

`Specialisme` does not need to be a factor for this to work, but that might still be a good way of encoding the variable.